# Does WKWebView Support HTML5 Offline Application Cache?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

HTML5 Offline Application Cache Is supported on Safari but is it supported in WKWebView?

I found some links here on StackOverflow but I am unable to implement these methods.

```
@interface WKPreferences (MyPreferences)
- (void)_setOfflineApplicationCacheIsEnabled:(BOOL)offlineApplicationCacheIsEnabled;
@end
```

[Enable Application cache in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892898/enable-application-cache-in-wkwebview?rq=1)

Some people are saying html5 application cache not supported in WKWebView.

[WKWebView Cache manifest not working IOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219778/wkwebview-cache-manifest-not-working-ios8?rq=1)

but I did not find out any docs or references about this in apple docs.

Comment: Have you already tried `webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest((new NSUrl("{URL HERE}")), NSUrlRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, 10000));` Here's a good resource https://inneka.com/programming/swift/swift-ios-cache-wkwebview-content-for-offline-view/

Comment: [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequestcachepolicy/nsurlrequestuseprotocolcachepolicy?language=objc) is the document about NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy and maybe help. This api you posted in the question is an private api.